# Change Windows 7 Window Colour

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winapi, windows-7

I've got a question but not sure if its possible. Is it possible to change the Windows 7 Window colour from .Net.

So this isn't the content of the window as that is easy i'm talking about the header title itself and allow the .Net app make the header transaperant like you can have in Window 7 and change the colour too etc.. Is there some sort of Window api that i can hook into to do this that anyone knows of.

The reason i want to do this is in Window you can obviously set your theme and window colours but i want my app to have all dialogs with the same sort of styling so i can change the window content but the window header i can't and if the user has set their window colour to a strange colour then it looks strange against my themed app.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Iffy.

Comment: I know this is possible with themeux.dll; but there is little/no documentation around it. You may find success with Googling it - and with it you can change the theme for your window alone.

Answer (score 8):

> i can't and if the user has set their window colour to a strange colour then it looks strange against my themed app.

That should be left up to the user, and you should not change settings that are explicitly set by the user for their operating system installation. This will drive more users away. If this is for your own personal use then it would be okay, but don't change a users Windows settings (of any kind).

If it really looks that bad, you should consider a custom skinned Window for your application only.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible. This is a MSDN article describing it:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb688195%28VS.85%29.aspx

The code is in C++ but it should be easy to get it working in C#